# RandomPrime inside Manipulate gets evaluated multiple times

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, random

```
Manipulate[
m = RandomPrime[d];
{m, d},
{d, {20, 50}, SetterBar}
]
```

Basically, I expected the code to generate a random prime *m* (under the upper bound *d*) for me to make some graphics about *m*. However, the piece of code evaluates m multiple times, which is bewildering to me. Probably I need to use Dynamic here, but I have not figured it out.

**How can I evaluate the RandomPrime function for only once?**

Answer (score 2):

whenever you use Manipulate, use `TrackedSymbols` to tell it which symbols to track

```
Manipulate[m = RandomPrime[d];
 {m, d}, {d, {20, 50}, SetterBar},
 TrackedSymbols :> {d}]
```

Without this, it will track each symbol in its expression and if any changes, it will re-evaluate again automatically until no more changes are detected.